# Is SendMessage or SendMessageTimout thread safe?

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a very basic question : is SendMessage or SendMessageTimout  thread safe ?

SendMessage :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx

SendMessageTimout
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952(v=vs.85).aspx

#### Related:

- [Sending message from working non-gui thread to the main window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562689/sending-message-from-working-non-gui-thread-to-the-main-window)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending message from working non-gui thread to the main window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562689/sending-message-from-working-non-gui-thread-to-the-main-window)

Comment: SendMessage is thread-safe.  It is the code that runs when it delivers the message that is never ever thread-safe.

Comment: Assuming the `HWND` being sent to is itself thread-safe and not changed while `SendMessage/Timeout` is busy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SendMessage and SendMessageTimeout are blocking functions: They pause the sender until the receiver has processed the message and returned. So there is no concurrent access to anything, hence the operation is thread-safe.

Comment: I am missing the logic here. Say there are three threads A, B, C. Thread A is using SendMessage to send a message to thread B. The fact that thread A is blocked during the sending says nothing to the question of thread safety, when Thread C can send the same message to thread B at the same time, and could incur synchronization issue.